# Error while adding android platform for cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

```
D:\Shabbir\AndroidTest>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\Application Data\npm\node_modules\cordova\node
_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_mo
dules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\
lib\check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\.cordova\lib\android\cordova
\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\
node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\.cordova\lib\android\cord
ova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\.cordo
va\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\
node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3
.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

    at C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\Application Data\npm\node_modules\cordo
va\src\platform.js:244:30
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)

D:\Shabbir\AndroidTest>
```

This Error I got

I downloaded NodeJS and install Following

```
npm -g install phonegap

npm -g install cordova

npm -g install plugman

npm -g install ant
```

I set some path for that

```
PATH
C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\Application Data\npm;C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\Application Data\npm\node_modules\ant;C:\NEW ANDROID\sdk\platforms;C:\NEW ANDROID\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\Application Data\npm\node_modules\ant\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
```

this is ANT_HOME path that i downloaded from [here](http://apache.claz.org//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.zip)

```
ANT_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.3
```

also added JAVA_HOME , ANDROID_HOME

I did all possible ways but still found error PLZ help me to find solution
I think I confused to set a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much research work I found the answer.

I have not set path of the xcopy.

**xcopy.exe** - `this file contains sdk platform information.` So I added path of this. xcopy.exe is located in system32 folder.

So I added path like this and I able to add android platform.

%SystemRoot%\System32;

Answer (score 0):

this path issues

Click on the Start menu in the lower-left corner of the desktop, right-click on Computer, then click Properties.

Click Advanced System Settings in the column on the left.

In the resulting dialog box, press Environment Variables.

Select the PATH variable and press Edit.

Append the following to the PATH based on where you installed the SDK, for example

```
C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools
```

[refer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

[here for windows](http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html)

Comment: C:\NEW ANDROID\sdk\platform-tools;C:\NEW ANDROID\sdk\tools try this path

Comment: then type android tell me result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46401/discussion-between-sport-and-shabbir-dhangot)