# cordova platform add android not working

Tags: android, cordova

cordova platfrom add android not working on Windows7. Its giving following error.

C:\Users\user\cordova_projects\myapp>cordova platforms add android

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4

Creating android project...

Error: C:\Users\user.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\cr

eate.bat: Command failed with exit code -1073741819

```
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
```

dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)

```
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)

at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)

at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: do you have all paths set & pointing correctly? for node, sdk, ant.

Comment: yes i am having all paths set & pointing correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a path setting issue, I am too working on Window 7 and had similar issues initially when i had wrong path set. Plus there are no# of questions on SO where due to path have similar issues reported ...see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033015/how-to-create-project-in-ionic-cordova-and-android) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170288/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-on-mac-os?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402261/phonegap-cordova-error-when-adding-the-platform-android?rq=1).

Here is how I set paths, so you check and set yours accordingly, hope will help you.

**ANT_Home**: C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4

**Java_Home**: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60

**ANDROID_HOME**: C:\Android\AndroidSDK\sdk

and **path** variable references to three things:

**path**:.;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;

Comment: should i use variables like ANT_HOME JAVA_HOME ANDROID_HOME to store path then set these variable to PATH

Comment: its no necessary but it makes easier to read. The purpose is to provide valid paths.

Comment: I am having problem setting paths. i used setx PATH "%ANDROID_HOME%\bin" but its not working.

Comment: %Android_Home%\bin is wrong !! there is no folder "bin" inside Android_Home ...see my path settings carefully

Comment: I used **setx PATH "%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;"**

Comment: ok, please share all variables path settings in your question above as I shared.

Comment: My **ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4**

Comment: ANT_Home: C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4

Java_Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05

ANDROID_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk

Comment: read the last answer -the correct marked one at end. it talks about xcopy.exe path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431363/error-while-adding-android-platform-for-cordova

Comment: Now i am having this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144694/unable-to-run-node-on-cmd-windows-7) nothing is running on cmd. Though i have path set for every thing.

Comment: Now its working. But saying to install Android target "android-19"

Comment: ok good, now open Android SDK manager wizard and install the Android SDK 19. Because its trying to generate project on 19 which is currently not present on your machine.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. i have been trying to figure this out for last 6 days.

Comment: you welcome, see if your other issues is resolved too, or update on that question

Answer (score 0):

You should try clearing the cache:

`npm cache clean`

Comment: i tried npm cache clean. but nothing changes still getting same error.

Comment: Your listing for the problem looks a bit odd. A 304 response normally means that the android platform has already been added to this project. But then it attempts to create the android project which it will not do if it already exists. Also you are only displaying the error from the spawn process, normally you get an error listing from the actual script failure as well which may help identify what the actual error is.