# Unable to run node on cmd windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js

C:\Windows\system32>echo %path%

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin";C:\Windows\S

ystem32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Git\cmd;C:

\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\an

droid-studio\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sd

k\tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\

bin;

C:\Windows\system32>node

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Set its installation directory path

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

and the module location path

```
C:\Users\AAhad\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

and then on console run **node**

and check this as well: [Node.js doesn't recognize system path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768549/node-js-doesnt-recognize-system-path)

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/355594/windows-7s-path-and-environment-variables-are-corrupted) was the problem. got it solved.

Comment: oh , does it mean you had a very long path 2048 characters... Ok good to know that..thanks

Comment: Yeah. path was very long.